# Target Location in Sharing a Project using Egit

Tags: git, egit

I'm starting in git world now. So, I want to create a new repository using Egit.

I create a Java Project in Eclipse, after Team>Share Project.

The figure represents my window that I will describe below:

[image: share project]

My problem is: I have a project called eer and I want to create a repository inside C:\Users\Marcelo\github;

So, egit creates a new folder inside eer, so my path is C:\Users\Marcelo\github\eer\eer...

How to make egit don't create a new folder (project folder) inside a egit repository.

I want a path like this: C:\Users\Marcelo\github\eer\src; C:\Users\Marcelo\github\eer\doc ...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After push the create button, you put in parent directory C:\Users\Marcelo and the Name github.

Why?

Because the name of my local repository is github, and stays in C:\Users\Marcelo.

Using this, Eclipse put eer inside C:\Users\Marcelo\github